# Problem with Deluge: "no incoming connection!"

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I've been seeing the message "No incoming connections" at the bottom of my Deluge program, but not in the web Deluge.

I tried turning firewall off and see if it removes, but it did not work.

I switched the ports to use random ports for both incoming and out coming connections in the preference settings, but it still won't disappear.

And I have a bunch off torrents that are queueing and not seeding when there are people downloading.

Answer (score 9):

I also had this problem, and was troubleshooting for the last few days. There was little information online; everything was telling me to do what the only other answer in this thread says, changing the ports deluge was using. This didn't work, so I began changing random settings and seeing if they affected it. On the below screen I had everything set to -1, and as soon as I changed them Deluge started working fine. I'm not sure which setting it is but I don't care, as long as I can torrent.

[image]

Comment: Any further info on this?
I still have the same issue. But also get tracker connection errors.
like you, there is very little info out there about this and other networking setup.

Comment: I tried this by setting arbitrarily large values instead of -1 and this worked (Deluge 1.3.15 on Windows 10).

Answer (score 5):

There is one thing to do: check in preferences if deluge sees the port it uses as "open" with the "test active port" check. Do not use "random ports" and use ports between 50000 and 59999 (the default ports used by torrent programs are sometimes blocked by ISPs).

[image]

If it does not show it is active you need to open the ports you selected in your router in the section "port forwarding". [Here is a how to for a lot of routers](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm) (but with uTorrent but that does not matter for the router settings).

> but not in the web deluge

That one uses your internet port.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all methods proposed above, that didn't work. I restarted deluge and changed ports many times. 
I also checked it with `deluge -L debug`, but the error was not there.

I deleted all my torrents. Restarted deluge. It started to work.

Now everything works, but when I 'test active port', it shows the yellow triangle with exclamation (though it's no longer shown in the bottom line of the main window). So don't pay much attention to that 'test'.

Comment: Which version? Number? Install vs Portable? What steps  Remove, Restart & then Reinsert the Torrents?

Comment: @Alex-s sorry, I no longer have that laptop. I guess it was an official Fedora Core release from its repositories. Remove torrents just in the menu. Reopen then like you add new torrents. Restart = exit and open again.

Comment: @YN - Around when had you done this (with latest version from then)? Was it installer Deluge or Portable if at all you remember?

Comment: @Alex-s around the time I posted my answer :) April 2019. I suppose Fedora Core package may be several years older than the most recent version. Why are you interested? Are you a deluge developer? It was a package from one of the system repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I terminate processes that use certain port (in my case was 4001), it blocks incoming connections:

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:4001
kill -9 (process id)
```

Then I close Deluge, reopen it and it works as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some reason the incoming/outgoing interface was cleared (empty). After entering the `enp3s0` interface, the no incoming connection/port problem was gone.